# PHP-cgi stops working randomly without error log

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using nginx with (WT-NMP - portable mysql nginx php app.). Everything is working perfectly except php-cgi, it is stopping randomly and i have to start it again, in fact i realized that if i add to post my website quickly (in wordpress), it is definitely stopping. But sometimes it is stopping without for no reason, maybe there is a reason but i cant see because no error shows in errorlogs.

I searched on the internet and I found something about my problem but I couldn't use these methods on my windows server.

The solution I found: SET PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0 to the script that starts php-cgi.exe

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting PHP FastCGI...
SET PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0
SET PATH="D:\Program Files\php;%PATH%"
"C:\Program Files\php\php-cgi.exe" -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c "C:\Program Files\php\php.ini"
```

Any idea about my problem? or any idea how to use this codes on my windows server. I searched for windows and found only one solution, it was about the IIS.

The proccess: adding PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0 to environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

The following setting works fine for Windows 2012 R2 Server !!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrIaO.jpg

Control Panel-> System->Advanced System Settings->Advanced->Environment Variables->System Variables-> New -> Variable Name: PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS & Variable Value: 0

Comment: you may perhaps explain some reasons behind the same too.